# How do I loop through colors one at a time with each stroke on a canvas element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, canvas, asynchronous

I want to fill an HTML canvas with a gradient of colors. I understand there is a gradient method for this but I'm just trying to figure out, for the sake of learning, how i could do this by drawing vertical lines progressively by incrementing the x coordinate and the RGB value. (Or could this be easier with hex values?)

As I have my code now it just prints every line as red rather than starting at black and fading into red. Is this because of the asynchronicity of JavaScript?

Heres my code:

```
function drawLine() {
  var myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var maxX = 960;
  var maxY = 50;
  var red = 0;
  var green = 0;
  var blue = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 960; i++) {
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.lineTo(x, maxY);
    context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
    context.stroke();
    x++;
    red++;
  }
}

drawLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're having problem is because you didn't start making your line with `context.beginPath();`, which means that the next time you'll make a line, it'll incorporate also the previous line and so one and when you reach the last line and want to paint it, you'll also paint all other lines as well, in the same color.

So, add `context.beginPath();` before your `context.moveTo(x,y);`

Comment: @JakeStewart No problem. Also, put `context.lineWidth=1.5;` to avoid having it look half-translucent.

Comment: @JakeStewart if this answer resolved your issue please accept it, this helps the community by pointing future visitors to the best answer quickly. It also gives reputation points to both you and Niddro.

Comment: Got it. First time asking a question here. Thanks again for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Something quick I put together using jQuery. I just increased the red value in this example. Hope it helps.

```js
function drawLine(){
    var x = 0;
    var red = 0;
    var green = 0;
    var blue = 0;
  
    for (var i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
      $('#canvas').append('<div class="line" style="background-color: rgb('+red+','+green+','+blue+');"></div>');
      red++;
    }
}
drawLine();
```

```css
#canvas{
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
}
#canvas .line{
    width: 0.39%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas"></div>
```